# How to arrange Database to allow for sub-users

Tags: database, mongodb

Im looking to make a web app dashboard where there is a main user then inside there are staff/sub users that can switch to their accounts
how would ago about this?
Example
Main Staff accounts(Admins) ---> SUB-Users

Have done research but I can't find a final answer for the backend, how the database would look.
TO clarify.
EXAMPLE
LOGIN TO MAIN COMPANY ACCOUNT(MANAGER)
IT THEN HAS OPTION TO SWITCH PROFILES INSIDE TO STAFF (SUB ACCOUNTS)

Comment: Do not refer to another link for the question context. Instead, [edit] your question to include the essential part of the question so when the link is broken, this question itself can remain intact.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.